# Django create unique foreign key objects

Tags: python, django

I have a FK in my Django model, that needs to be unique for every existing model existing before migration:

```
class PNotification(models.Model):
    notification_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    # more fields to come

def get_notifications():
    noti = PNotification.objects.create()
    logger.info('Created notifiactions')
    logger.info(noti.notification_id)
    return noti.notification_id

class Product(models.Model):
        notification_object = models.ForeignKey(PNotification, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=get_notifications)
```

When migrating, I get three `PNotification` objects saved into the database, however each existing `Product` is linked with notification_id=1, so each existing `Product` gets linked with the same `PNotification` object. I thought the method call in `default` would be executed for each existing `Product`?
How can I give each existing `Product` a unique `PNotification` object?

Comment: Well you put the `ForeignKey` relaton on the `Product` model meaning each `Product` can have only one `PNotification` but one `PNotification` can have many `Product`s - maybe you want to swap that relation?

Comment: You could add unique=True to the notification_object.

Comment: @ger.s.brett using unique=True will throw IntegrityErrors because then also each Product gets the same PNotification.

Comment: @Daniel It will be a OneToOne, but I am working with FK here for testing. Each Product will have exactly one PNotification and one PNotification belongs to one product

Answer (score 1):

I also suspected that a new PNotification would be created wth your setup. It appears as if the method is being called on the class decleration and not instance creation.

Maybe an overridden save method is a better approach here? Note, you'll need to change the logic slightly for `OneToOneField`s:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if not self.notification_object.all():

            notification = PNotification.objects.create()

            self.notification_object.add(notification)
                
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Just one question: this will not help with migration, will it? For newly created products my code works, it is just about migrating

Comment: That's a good point - but you can easily add: `for p in Product.objects.all(): p.save()` somewhere in your code temporarily to trigger the save method for existing objects during a migration / connected to a specific view, etc. That is generally what I do when making changes to existing instances.

Comment: Yea, I think that is way easier than writing a migration or SQL script